# Simple program to cap a computer's fan speed at a given RPM

Tags: gratis

Not looking for cooling curves or anything fancy. Just something that overrides existing behavior to cap the fan speed at a given RPM through a slider control or similar.

Operating system: Windows 10

Other requests: No bundled adware/crapware. No dodgy download links/sites known to bundle adware/crapware.

Comment: Please add to your question (and tags, if appropriate) operating system(s) and price range.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no API to control fans on Windows, therefore the program would have to directly communicate with the used fan control chip that exists in quite a few different brands and models. Ten years ago ther was some software available to do so but nowadays most boards already have a fan control functionality in BIOS and other people just use the software provided by the manufacturer.